# How do you make a disk partition in linux

Tags: partition, disk

Looking for an ideal process to make a new partition on a disk with...

- recognizing the need to identify the correct disk(s) out of many that may be installed
- identifying necessary steps needed from start to finish; is it just set partition type GPT then make partition 1 type XFS from sector A to B, and partition 2 from C to D?
- sizing a partition based on size in GB or % of space available rather than deal with sector numbers.
- I guess do on command line, does everything boil down to some `parted` in linux?  Is there anything better?

Please share your method of how you like to create primary (or other) disk partitions on disks other than your operating system disk.  I am using RHEL7 but if the method is universal then even better.

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of preference, really. To new users, I recommend `gparted`. The UI is quite intuitive.

For more control, I prefer the command-line tools. For GPT, it is `gdisk`. The `n` command takes a start addresses and either an end or a partition size. Unit can be sectors or (tera/giga/mega)bytes.
`gdisk` is interactive and asks for all information in a dialog fashion. Simply press `n` to create a new partition and follow the instructions. Finish your work by pressing `w`. Quit `gdisk` by pressing `q` to exit without saving the changes. For more commands, press `h`.

Comment: You are assuming that the system has an X environment. You mentioned command line tools but it would help if you'd give an explanation of how to use them.

Comment: There's also sgdisk which is a real command line version of gdisk, that is also usable for scripting.

Comment: @NasirRiley I am assuming the operator uses an X environment. From the nature of the question I further assume the asker is not a die-hard text-terminal-only user. X forwarding exists. Wayland offers a compatibility layer.

Comment: You don't know that there's an X environment nor is their any information in the question to indicate that there is. It's better though that you gave some instructions to indicate how to use one of the command line tools.